# Localization of Exception Message inside class files?

Tags: c#, exception, localization

If a class file contains some initial validation and throws an `Exception` in the case where validation fails,

- is it considered good practice to enable localization inside the class files for the `Exception Message`?
- How would I catch these localized exceptions? Simple string comparison of the `Exception Message` seems... not elegant to say the least. Are there preferred and proven better ways to approach this?

an example of how I was planning this:

```
private ResourceManager localization;

private string email;

public string Email
{
    get { return email; }
    set
    {
        if (value.Length > 50)
            throw new ArgumentException(localization.GetString("toolong_email"));
        else if (!IsValidEmail(value))
            throw new ArgumentException(localization.GetString("invalid_email"));
        else
            email = value;
    }
}
```

Microsoft's [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) states: "Include a localized description string in every exception."

I've tagged this C# but in the end this is more about general practices, I suppose. I was thinking that this might be more of a *programmers.stackexchange* question but decided to post it here. Unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow a `System.Net.WebException` design and pass an error type (like it's done with the `Status` property of the mentioned exception class) that is easy to work with from code. The exception message itself can be localized (like any other CLR exceptions that use resources rather than hardcoded strings, as far as I remember).

Another solution would be to throw different exceptions for different types of errors:

```
 if (value.Length > 50)
    {
      throw new ValueLengthExceededException("Email", 
        localization.GetString("toolong_email"));
    }
    else if (!IsValidEmail(value))
    {
      /* 
        Or a generic "InvalidFormatException/FormatException" with 
        member name like a previous example. 
      */
      throw new InvalidEmailException(localization.GetString("invalid_email")); 
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, this is where I was in doubt as well: I have a bunch of classes modeled against a database. If I were to make derived `Exception` classes, that could easily run in the dozens. Not that I'm reluctant to do so, I was wondering if there wasn't a more "generic" approach.

Comment: @WimOmbelets As I suggested in a first paragraph, you could combine "error code" approach with exceptions. It might be a way to go in your case.